# To show links like previous 1 2 3 4 5.... next

Tags: php, pagination

The following code just show next and previous links in pagination:

```
if( $page > 1 ) {
echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.($page-1).'&date1='.$_REQUEST["date1"].'&date2='.$_REQUEST["date2"].'">Previous</a>';
}
if( $page < $totalPages ) {
echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.($page+1).'&date1='.$_REQUEST["date1"].'&date2='.$_REQUEST["date2"].'">Next</a>';
}
```

what should I do to show links like this:
`previous 1 2 3 4 5..... next`

Comment: ?page=1 ?page=2 ?page=3 ?page=4 ?page=5 ?

Comment: There are _millions_ of exampels and solutions for this if you consult google. _Did you?_

Comment: yeah I tried but fails. will you please suggest any links???

Comment: Be careful with including `$_REQUEST` or `$_GET` directly into your HTML without escaping it - that's a simple XSS vulnerability right there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code.

```
<?php
if( $page > 1 ) {
echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.($page-1).'&date1='.$_REQUEST["date1"].'&date2='.$_REQUEST["date2"].'">Previous</a>';
}
for( $i = 1; $i < $totalPages; $i++){
    echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='. $i .'&date1='.$_REQUEST["date1"].'&date2='.$_REQUEST["date2"].'">' . $i . '</a>';
}
if( $page < $totalPages ) {
echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.($page+1).'&date1='.$_REQUEST["date1"].'&date2='.$_REQUEST["date2"].'">Next</a>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop up to totalpages, something like this:

```
for( $i = 1; $i < $totalPages; $i++){
    echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='. $i .'">' . $i . '</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
foreach ($totalPages as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry. The & means pass the variable by reference, rather than passing the value of the variable - which is not necessary in this case. The quotes are messy, edited that out. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I know what `&` does, but was asking what it was doing in this case `:)`. I assume `$totalPages` is an integer, so you won't be able to iterate it as an array - suspect a `for` would be more appropriate here.

Comment: You're right. For would be more appropriate. Thanks for the heads up :)